# Word document in RichTextBox - C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, richtextbox

Does anyone know how one would go about loading a Word document into a RichTextBox or is it even possible.

Comment: depending on the contents/format of the word document this won't be possible... best bet is to save the word document as RTF and load that... if you really must render/edit/load word documents then there are components (commercial) for that... is this an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word doc can have more on it than just text such as pictures, shapes, and controls. If you wanted to convert a word document to rich text, you'd probably have to parse it and convert it yourself.

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/wordfromdotnet11082005235506pm/wordfromdotnet.aspx) link give you some insight for the same.